# Overriding method in subclass with a parameter type hint that is a subclass of the type hint used in the parent's method

Tags: python, inheritance, types, overriding, type-hinting

I have the following structure of a parent class and a child class which inherits from parent. The constructor of the parent takes a parameter of type `ParentType`, and the constructor of the child class takes the same parameter, but of type `ChildType`, which is a subclass of `ParentType`.

The code runs fine, however mypy complains as it is inferring the type of the parameter from the parent class and not the subclass.

```py
class ParentType:
    def __init__(self, param_1: int):
        self.param_1 = param_1


class ChildType(ParentType):
    def __init__(self, param_1: int, param_2: int):
        super().__init__(param_1=param_1)
        self.param_2 = param_2


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a: ParentType):
        self.a = a


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: ChildType):
        super().__init__(a=a)


child_type = ChildType(param_1=1, param_2=2)
child = Child(a=child_type)
print(child.a.param_1)  # works
print(child.a.param_2)  # works, but mypy complains that "ParentType" has no attribute "param_2"; maybe "param_1"?
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the correct way (might also depend on your actual problem), but my first instinct would be to use a [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types) for the type of `a`.

You can create a [type variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) `T` that stands for any subtype of `ParentType`. Then you can make `Parent` generic with parameter `T` and say that `Child` should be a `Parent[ChildType]`.

Complete example:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

class ParentType:
    def __init__(self, param_1: int):
        self.param_1 = param_1


class ChildType(ParentType):
    def __init__(self, param_1: int, param_2: int):
        super().__init__(param_1=param_1)
        self.param_2 = param_2


T = TypeVar('T', bound=ParentType)

class Parent(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a = a


class Child(Parent[ChildType]):
    def __init__(self, a: ChildType):
        super().__init__(a=a)


child_type = ChildType(param_1=1, param_2=2)
child = Child(a=child_type)
print(child.a.param_1)
print(child.a.param_2)
```

If the only difference between `Parent` and `Child` is the type of `a`, you wouldn't even need `Child` anymore.
You could just do:

```py
child = Parent(a=child_type)
```

**Edit: Another solution**

You can also simply specify the type of `a` in `Child`:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    a: ChildType
    def __init__(self, a: ChildType):
        super().__init__(a=a)
```